# SQL Server query to update one table column value with another table value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want update `one table` column value from `another table`. I have two table i.e. `Users, UserProfile` I have `MobileNumber` column in both table. So I want to update `Users` table mobile number from `UserProfile`. There may be duplicate mobilenumber in `UserProfile` table. So I want to avoid duplicate value in `Users` table. If there is already `MobileNumber` exists then no need to update.

Here is my `query`

```
update Users 
set MobileNumber = up.MobileNumber
from Users u 
left join UserProfile up on u.UserID = up.UserID
where up.MobileNumber not in (select ISNULL(MobileNumber, '') from Users);
```

But it is not working correctly. In `UserProfile` table there are some records which contains `Null` value in `MobileNumber`. How can I update this column without duplicates?

Comment: Your query works perfectly. Where is the problem you are facing.@Ajay

Comment: A clarification please. Is there 1 record per user in Users and many records per user in UserProfile?

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry for confusion. In userprofile table mobilenumber may be same for multiple users. In UserProfile there is only one record for single user like `User.UserId = UserProfile.UserId`  you will find only one record.

Comment: @P.Salmon & @akash When updating `MobileNumber` I want to check weather this `MobileNumber` is not already exists in `User` table. If exists no need to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution

```
Update u set u.MobileNumber = up.MobileNumber
FROM Users u
JOIN(
 SELECT MobileNumber, MIn(UserId) AS UsID FROm UserProfile
 group by MobileNumber
) up
on u.UserID = up.UsID
```

Comment: Great, you find the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

MERGE will help you:

```
MERGE Users as target
USING (
    SELECT DISTINCT up.UserID, up.MobileNumber 
    FROM UserProfile up 
    WHERE up.MobileNumber NOT IN (SELECT MobileNumber FROM Users WHERE MobileNumber IS NOT NULL)) as source
ON target.UserID = source.UserID
WHEN MATCHED AND target.MobileNumber IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE SET MobileNumber = source.MobileNumber;
```

But if you got more then 1 `MobileNumber` for some `userid`'s you must change `SELECT DISTINCT UserID, MobileNumber FROM UserProfile WHERE MobileNumber IS NOT NULL` part to something like that `SELECT DISTINCT UserID, MAX(MobileNumber) FROM UserProfile WHERE MobileNumber IS NOT NULL GROUP BY UserID` or write your own query to chose what you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your ans. but it is still adding duplicate mobile number in `Users` table for user. In `Users & UserProfile` there is only one record for single user like `User.UserId = UserProfile.UserId` you will find only one record. But mobile number may be same for many users in userprofile table.

Comment: When updating `MobileNumber` I want to check weather this `MobileNumber` is not already exists in `User` table. If exists no need to update.

Comment: Then add EXISTS statement to source query. Or try to use query from my answer, I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried your new query. But result set `0 row affected`

Comment: Maybe inner join not working as expected. Give it try now, I changed query

Comment: Finally I got solution. Please see my ans. post.